# open app automatically when fcm notification is received while app is kill or on background

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-notifications

**how to resolve this issue any one give send me any solution according to this issues**

*fcm notification is received but app not opened   how to handle it*

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(INTENT_FILTER);
        sendBroadcast(intent);

        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            utils.print(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
            utils.print(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getData());
            //Calling method to generate notification
            if (SharedHelper.getKey(this,"loggedIn").equalsIgnoreCase(getString(R.string.True))) {

                sendNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
            }
        }
```

Comment: please any one gsend some solution of this issue how to automatically open app when notification is recieve

Answer (score 0):

you should declare the firebase service class in Manifest like this:

```
 <service android:name="your_service>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: i am also use like that fcm notification is recieved but  i want  to open automatically open app when notification is recieved                                                                                          '<service
            android:name=".FCM.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService"
            tools:ignore="ExportedService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>